# Delete the entire row in an excel using openpyxl by taking 1st column as reference?

Tags: python, openpyxl

This code is deleting only the first column

```
import openpyxl

wb1=openpyxl.load_workbook('SRS_Re-Import_reportn.xlsx')

wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('new_file.xlsx')

ws1=wb1['Sheet']

ws2=wb2['Sheet']

ws1 = wb1.active

values = []

for i in range(2,ws1.max_row+1):

  if ws1.cell(row=i,column=1).value in values:

    pass 

  else:

    values.append(ws1.cell(row=i,column=1).value)

for value in values:

  ws2.append([value])

wb2.save('new_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear what your code is meant to me doing. Are you looking to remove duplicate rows based on the 'index' first column?

Comment: yes based on the 1st column need to delete the entire duplicate rows

Comment: This code deletes nothing.

Comment: please help to delete the duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases like this, the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) library has built in functions to perform this common operation.

if you don't have pandas installed you can install it with `pip install pandas`

```py
import pandas

input_file = 'SRS_Re-Import_reportn.xlsx'
output_file = 'new_file.xlsx'

df = pandas.read_excel(input_file)
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=1) #use subset to select which column to look for duplicate values
df2.to_excel(output_file)
```

Comment: can we delete duplicate rows using openpyxl

Comment: openpyxl is a library for reading and writing excel files, not a data manipulation library. You're only writing the first column in your new file because that's the only data you're reading into your list, you need to loop through to your max column to include the row. Any reason why you can't use another library with the built in functionality

Comment: Because Im using only openpyxl library in my script, no need to import new library

Answer (score 0):

You can find and delete duplicate rows with openpyxl.

```
row_numbers_to_delete = []
rows_to_keep = []
for row in ws.rows:
    working_list = []
    for cell in row:
        working_list.append(cell.value)
    if working_list not in rows_to_keep:
        rows_to_keep.append(working_list)
    else:
        row_numbers_to_delete.append(cell.row)
for row in row_numbers_to_delete:
    ws.delete_rows(
        idx=row,
        amount=1
    )
```